# No encuentra registros en una coleccion concreta - API / Node.js

Tags: nodejs, api

antes de nada decir que es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta en esta web, así que perdón de antemano por si escribo o digo algo mal y gracias también. Empiezo el problema.

Tengo una base de datos hosteada en mLab en MongoDB, las peticiones que realiza mi API a esta base de datos las hace perfectamente, pero recién cree una colección nueva y parece que la API no encuentra resultados, (solo tiene un registro).

Voy a poner solo el código que creo que da el error, ya que como he dicho, todas las demás funciones funcionan correctamente, pero esta me esta dando problemas, y no se exactamente donde estará el error, si en el modelo, en los controls, o la propia base de datos de mLab. La colección se llama **asignacionMatricula** en la base de datos. Preguntarme lo que querías, si necesitáis mas código o algo preguntadme sin pudor. Soy bastante Junior pero me gusta aprender, gracias de antemano!

**Controls.js**

```
    var asignacionMatricula = require("../models/asignacionMatricula")

function matriculaAsignada(req, res) {
// METODO GET
// * idUsuario : id del usuario logeado
if (req.params.idUsuario) {
    var idUsuario = req.params.idUsuario
    asignacionMatricula.find({ "idUsuario": idUsuario }).exec(function (err, matriculaAsignada) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error en el servidor",
                messageError: err,
            })
        } else {
            if (matriculaAsignada != 0) {
                res.status(200).send({
                    matricula: matriculaAsignada
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: "Matriculas no encontradas",
                    idUsuario: req.params.idUsuario
                })
            }
        }
    })
} else {
    res.status(200).send({
        error: "Falta el parametro de la url en la peticion"
    })
}


module.exports = {
matriculaAsignada }
```

**Models / asignacionMatricula.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var asignacionMatriculaSchema = Schema({

idUsuario: String,
idMatricula: String

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('asignacionMatricula' , 
asignacionMatriculaSchema);
```

**Routes**

```
var express = require('express')
var UsersController = require('../controllers/controls')

var api = express.Router()

api.get("/matriculaAsignada/:idUsuario", UsersController.matriculaAsignada)

module.exports = api;
```

**EDIT1**: Imagen de la colección y un registro, estoy buscandolo por el campo "idUsuario" y estoy usando la siguiente ruta en el Postman. 
**ruta** : https://proyecto-mdc-api.herokuapp.com/matriculaAsignada/5cc5c6e3fb6fc00ed59cd8a8.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Si estás buscando por ID, ¿estás seguro de que la ID es la correcta?

Comment: Como @PabloLozabo comenta, falta que indiques cuál es el error. También es necesario que indiques si tus rutas están en el orden esperado. Me explico, si tienes una ruta que apunta a `/matriculaAsignada/algoMasAqui` declarada antes de tu ruta que manejas con `/matriculaAsignada/:idUsuario`, entonces esta última nunca será usada. Por eso es bueno que indiques cuál es el error que estás obteniendo (en caso que obtengas alguno). Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, no me devuelve ningún error, solo me dice que no ha encontrado ninguna matricula, voy a editar y os voy a poner una imagen de la colección para que veáis el registro al que quiero acceder. Comento también que estoy usando Potsman para las peticiones, pero este no devuelve un error de node, sino la respuesta de que no hay matriculas con ese id, cuando los he copiado y pegado. Perdonad mi ignorancia y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Tampoco uso rutas que están por detrás de /matriculaAsignada, son absolutas tal y como podéis ver en la ruta que he pasado.